# How to map or assign an entry to an array-item based on some of this item's conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping, mutation

I have array of objects,

if the name  is `xx` then push xitems to that object and

if the name  is `yy` then push yitems to that object

Below is the code tried , and also should not use spread operator

```
const result = [];
var ss=arrobj.forEach(function(e){
 if(e.name === 'xx'){
   result.push({id: e.id, name: e.name, country:e.country, others: xitems})
 }
if(e.name === 'yy'){
  result.push({id: e.id, name: e.name, country:e.country,  others: yitems})
 }
return result;
});
```

```
var arrobj =[
  {id:1, name: "xx", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "yy", country: "MY"},
]

xitems =[
 {title: "Finance", valid: true}
]

yitems =[
 {title: "Sales", valid: true}
]

Expected Output
[
  {id:1, name: "xx", country: "IN", 
   others:[
   {title: "Finance", valid: true}
   ]
  },
  {id:2, name: "yy", country: "MY", 
    others: [
      {title: "Sales", valid: true}
     ]
  },
]
```

Comment: You could use `.map` for this.

Comment: @yainspan thanks for reply, updated, i used forEach

Comment: Your code is working fine. I did not see any issue.

Comment: @dev ... Regarding the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.map` for this.

```js
const arrobj = [
  { id: 1, name: "xx", country: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yy", country: "MY" },
];

const xitems = [{ title: "Finance", valid: true }];

const yitems = [{ title: "Sales", valid: true }];

const result = arrobj.map((item) => {
  if (item.name === "xx") {
    item.others = xitems;
  } else if (item.name === "yy") {
    item.others = yitems;
  }

  return item;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, the only issue that I identified are.

- There is no need to assign `var ss` with `arrobj.forEach`. Because [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) donot return a value.
- No need of `return result;` inside `Array.forEach`.
- Also as an improvement you can simply assign the object with key `others` like `Object.assign({}, e, { others: xitems })`, rather than returning individual key value.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const arrobj = [
  { id: 1, name: "xx", country: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yy", country: "MY" },
]

const xitems = [
  { title: "Finance", valid: true }
]

const yitems = [
  { title: "Sales", valid: true }
]

const result = [];
arrobj.forEach(function (e) {
  if (e.name === 'xx') {
    result.push(Object.assign({}, e, { others: xitems }))
  }
  if (e.name === 'yy') {
    result.push(Object.assign({}, e, { others: yitems }))
  }
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) based approach as well but without the `if` clauses which explicitly check for expected values of the mapped item's `name` property.

The approach instead utilizes [`map`'s 2nd `thisArg` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) which gets applied as the mapper functions `this` context. Such an additional object can be provided as a map/index of custom key value pairs where `key` equals a mapped item's `name`.

Thus ***the mapper implementation features generic code***, and due to the `this` binding it will be provided as function statement which makes it also re-usable and, if properly named, readable / comprehensible / maintainable too.

```js
function assignBoundNamedValueAsOthers(item) {
  // the bound key value pairs.
  const index = this;

  // create new object and assign, according to
  // `item.name`, bound named value as `others`.
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    item,
    { others: index[item.name] ?? [] },
  );
}

const arrobj = [
  { id: 1, name: "xx", country: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yy", country: "MY" },
];
const xitems = [{ title: "Finance", valid: true }];
const yitems = [{ title: "Sales", valid: true }];

const result = arrobj
  .map(assignBoundNamedValueAsOthers, {
    // each `key` equals an expected item's `name`.
    xx: xitems,
    yy: yitems,
  });

console.log({
  result,
  arrobj,
  xitems,
  yitems,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

As one can see, the above implementation via [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) creates a new object from each mapped `arrobj` item. Thus the original item-references remains untouched / non mutated. It does not apply for the items of `xitems` and `yitems` since both array references are directly assigned each to its newly created `others` property. The above log does reflect this.

In case the goal was an entirely reference free data structure one needs to slightly change the `Object.assign` part of `assignBoundNamedValueAsOthers` ...

```js
function assignBoundNamedValueAsOthers(item) {
  // the bound key value pairs.
  const index = this;

  // create new object and assign, according to
  // `item.name`, bound named value as `others`.
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    item, {
      others: (index[item.name] ?? [])
        // dereference the `others` items as well.
        .map(othersItem =>
          Object.assign({}, othersItem)
        )
    },
  );
}

const arrobj = [
  { id: 1, name: "xx", country: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yy", country: "MY" },
];
const xitems = [{ title: "Finance", valid: true }];
const yitems = [{ title: "Sales", valid: true }];

const result = arrobj
  .map(assignBoundNamedValueAsOthers, {
    // each `key` equals an expected item's `name`.
    xx: xitems,
    yy: yitems,
  });

console.log({
  result,
  arrobj,
  xitems,
  yitems,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In case the OP does not need to care about immutability, the entire process then changes from a `map` task to a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) task, where `assignBoundNamedValueAsOthers` does directly change/mutate each currently processed `item` of `arrobj`, thus [`forEach` does not return any data but always the `undefined` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) ...

```js
function assignBoundNamedValueAsOthers(item) {
  // the bound key value pairs.
  const index = this;

  // mutate the original reference of the currently
  // processed `item` by directly assigning, according
  // to `item.name`, the bound named value as `others`.
  Object.assign(
    item,
    { others: index[item.name] ?? [] },
  );
  // no explicit return value due to
  // going to be used as a `forEach` task.
}

const arrobj = [
  { id: 1, name: "xx", country: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yy", country: "MY" },
];
const xitems = [{ title: "Finance", valid: true }];
const yitems = [{ title: "Sales", valid: true }];

// mutates each item of `arrobj`.
arrobj.forEach(assignBoundNamedValueAsOthers, {

  // each `key` equals an expected item's `name`.
  xx: xitems,
  yy: yitems,
});

console.log({
  arrobj,
  xitems,
  yitems,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are references to an object that has a value, variables do not store values. It is pointless to try to use a variable in that manner unless you have specific parameters. If you insist on a condition then you need to identify `xitems` and `yitems` by the objects values and/or properties or by the order they came in. If you have dynamic data how would you know what `xitems` or `yitems` really is?

The example below has been made reusable as long as you meet these requirements:

- Must have an array of objects as a primary parameter.
- Must have at least one array of objects for each object in the primary array. If there's more the rest will be ignored.
- The secondary array of objects must be in the order you want then to end up as.

The second parameter is a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (not a spread operator, although I have no idea why OP does not want to use it). This will allow us to stuff in as many object arrays as we want.

```
const distOther = (main, ...oAs) => {...
```

Next we create an array of pairs from all of the secondary arrays

```
let others = oAs.map(sub => ['others', sub]);
// [['others', [{...}]], [['others', [{...}]], ...]
```

Then we turn our attention to the primary array. We'll work our way from the inside out. `.map()` each object as an array of pairs by `Object.entries()`:

```
  main.map((obj, idx) => 
//  ...
    Object.entries(obj)
//  ...
// [{A: 1, B: 2}, {...}] => [[['A', 1], ['B', 2]], [[...], [...]]]
```

Then `.concat()` (a spead operator would be more succinct) each array of pairs with that of the secondary array of pairs corresponding to the current index (you'll need to wrap each secondary array in another array, so the return will level off correctly):

```
// main.map((obj, idx) => 
//   ...
//   Object.entries(obj)
     .concat([others[idx]])));
// [[['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['others', [{...}]], [[...], [...], ['others', [{...}]]]
```

Finally we'll use `Object.fromEntries()` to convert each array of pairs into an object.

```
// main.map((obj, idx) =>
     Object.fromEntries(
//   Object.entries(obj)
//   .concat([others[idx]])));
// [{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'others': [{...}]},...]
```

```js
const objArr =[
  {id:1, name: "xx", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "yy", country: "MY"},
];

const x =[
 {title: "Finance", valid: true}
]

const y =[
 {title: "Sales", valid: true}
]

const distOther = (main, ...oAs) => {
let others = oAs.map(sub => ['others', sub]);

return main.map((obj, idx) =>
Object.fromEntries(
Object.entries(obj)
.concat([others[idx]])));
};

console.log(distOther(objArr, x, y));
```